# Performance question: A better way to do "CASE, LOCATE then GROUP BY"

Tags: mysql

I have the following 2 tables `field_allowed` and `person`:

#### field_allowed

```
#person_id, field, 
1         ,name
1         ,email
1         ,phone
2         ,name
2         ,phone
3         ,phone
```

#### person

```
#person_id, name, email,           phone
1         , Mary, 123@example.com, 12345671
2         , John, 124@example.com, null
3         , Jack, 125@example.com, 12345673
```

And I want the following outcome, an access control on the person data:

```
#person_id, name, email,           phone
1         , Mary, 123@example.com, 12345671
2         , John, N/A            , null
3         , N/A , N/A            , 12345673
```

---

I only found one dumb ways to achieve this output

```
SELECT 
    person.person_id,
    CASE
        WHEN LOCATE('name', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT field)) THEN person.name
        ELSE 'N/A'
    END AS name,
    CASE
        WHEN LOCATE('email', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT field)) THEN person.email
        ELSE 'N/A'
    END AS email,
    CASE
        WHEN LOCATE('phone', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT field)) THEN person.phone
        ELSE 'N/A'
    END AS phone
FROM
    person
        JOIN
    field_allowed ON field_allowed.person_id = person.person_id
GROUP BY person.person_id
```

I found the use of `GROUP_CONCAT` AND `LOCATE` just seems way too dirty, there got to be a better way to do it.

Hence I would like to ask if there is a better way to do the above? I have control over the database schema, so schema can be changed as well that helps.

#### Edit:

Please be note that **when not found, showing 'N/A' is a requirement** and **the name can be < 3** characters. So the answer `MAX(CASE WHEN f.field = 'name' THEN name ELSE '' END) AS name)` will not be able to show some of the names.

Comment: can you please post the structure of the tables?

Comment: I have put the structure of the 2 tables already (See the 2 bold table name), would like to know what else I missed to inform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use conditional aggregation to get the result you want, utilising the fact that `MAX` of `NULL` and a non-empty string will return the non-empty string. When no value is available, `MAX` will return `NULL` and `COALESCE` can be used to convert that value to `N/A`:

```
SELECT p.person_id,
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN f.field = 'name' THEN name END), 'N/A') AS name,
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN f.field = 'email' THEN email END), 'N/A') AS email,
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN f.field = 'phone' THEN phone END), 'N/A') AS phone
FROM person p
JOIN field_allowed f ON f.person_id = p.person_id
GROUP BY p.person_id
```

Output:

```
person_id   name    email           phone
1           Mary    123@example.com 12345671
2           John    N/A             null
3           N/A     N/A             12345673
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6Jiz61SXZtXCC2Ubuoqg5N/1)

Comment: That seems very promising, thanks Nick I will check it out and accept the answer if it work on my datasets!

Comment: Hi Nick, please see the Edit above, unfortunately some of our `name` will be less than 3 so your answer cannot be accepted.

Comment: @NgSekLong see my edit. I think it will do what you want.

Comment: Yes! It does what I want, thanks for answering my question and let me know the MySQL function `COALESCE`  exists.